# What is this 6-pin integrated circuit marked with 4N25 and V41624?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification

What is the integrated circuit at U4?

This is the board for a Speed Queen laundry machine. I know the H5 connector can be used to start a laundry cycle. I don't know what signal it needs to start. H5 is connected to the two top-left pins of U4.

[image: U4 Component on circuit board]

I can identify the following text on the chip:

4N25
V41624

This is the board I'm trying to integrate with: [Kimball Control Board A01996](https://a-zapplianceparts.com/products/kimball-electronics-control-board-a01996-512621-7080784-nt86). I am unable to find a schematic for it.
The board uses 24 VAC.

I intend to use H5 to start the machine.

Comment: Probably an opto-isolator of some type (there are thousands to choose from). Good luck.

Comment: You need to be able to read the unreadable letters to figure out what it is.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to know what you are dealing with at H5, is it some digital DC signal like 24VDC?

Comment: @greybeard they do :). I fixed that one. Thanks.

Comment: For better readability of the marking it sometimes helps to clean the component surface beforehand (using isopropyl alcohol or circuit board cleaner) and then
1. apply Scotch Magic™ Tape (https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/comments/6o8oww/to_reveal_the_text_on_a_semiconductors_package/) 
or 2. take a very small amount of white thermal paste and smear it over the surface (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCm3YS9Eelw).
or 3. do the same with a white (chalk) pencil (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rl5jaN8dRDk)

Comment: If isopropyl alcohol has no affect (the board seems to be conformal-coated) then try lacquer thinner on a swab.  If *that* has no affect, then repeat with a drop of conformal stripper and let soak for some hours.  Gentle scraping with a knife edge should get it all off.

Comment: I'd dare to say it's a photo-MOS relay, driving that *AVAIL_OUT* line as an isolated switch. An overload/overvoltage just burned it. Look for an AQVxxx part from Panasonic, they have tons, based on working voltage and currents - pinout looks to be that too

Comment: Thank you. I found the component.
[4N25 Optocoupler](https://docs.rs-online.com/7461/0900766b814ae2b8.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Vishay datasheet:

> The 4N25 family is an industry standard single channel phototransistor coupler. This family includes the 4N25, 4N26, 4N27, 4N28. Each optocoupler consists of gallium arsenide infrared LED and a silicon NPN phototransistor.
>
> [Optocoupler, Phototransistor Output, with Base Connection](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf)